Who would I call to inspect the integrity of a truss after an electrician cut into it?
I hired an electrician to install recessed lighting. They chopped away wood at the chord tie beam just above 4 of the lights.
They also cut into the chord tie beam with the hole saw on a few other lights.
The roof structure is made of 2 x 4 trusses 24 inches on center. from my research cutting into the chord tie beam is not allowed.
Who would I call to inspect the integrity of the structure and a ballpark figure of what it may cost.
Any advice would be very much appreciated

Since this is electrical work, I assume a permit was pulled. Did you point to the inspector that the electrician notched the trusses? AFAIK, trusses cannot be notched.

Get your local building inspector to check.  If no local building inspector(or brother to electrician), then a structural engineer.  After that it becomes a legal question, since the electrician should be responsible for fixing.

There are so many  LED "pancake" lights on the market that are UL listed, I don't understand why there would be a need to cut into any wood.  MOst all need just 1/2 inch, ( the thickness of drywall.) for the light fixture.

While costs are explicitly off-topic, the "ballpark" is "whatever is required to effect the truss manufacturer's specified repair".

The IRC explicitly says

R802.7.2 Engineered Wood Products


Cuts, notches and holes bored in
trusses, structural composite lumber, structural glue-laminated
members, cross-laminated timber members or I-joists are prohibited
except where permitted by the manufacturer's recommendations or where
the effects of such alterations are specifically considered in the
design of the member by a registered design professional.

So you don't need an engineer to give you an opinion on something that is prima facie illegal. You need to call your local building inspector/commissioner, who will fail the inspection. Then you take this failed inspection to your electrician and make them fix it.

100% agreed! Note that the fix will include having the electrician contact the truss manufacturer to find out from them what the repair is. Don't just let the sparky slap a piece of 2x4 over it and call it good. Ensure that the mfgrs stamped drawings are available for 1) the inspector to approve the work, and 2) for you to securely keep a copy for any future inspections, especially at sale time.

@ Freeman,  I agree with you completely. However in the real world the stamped or engineered drawings or even the truss schedule is nowhere to be found. This is especially true when the home has had its 3rd, 4th or more owner.  I remember needing an engineer to sign off on a truss modification I did, His reply when witnessing it was, "I can't calculate a load for that, but I know it's ok...I'll give you a letter of professional opinion."  Perhaps this is what the OP needs to look for.  It's a strange but real gap between what is needed and what one can get.
